# Wait for the delegates to be executed before return of the object of a class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegation

I am unit testing a class. The class is responsible for connecting to a peripheral and then discovering its services and characteristics using the delegates.

```
    func setupLightController() -> HueBTLightController
    {
        let btLight = HueBTLight(identifier: "093FB4B8-82E6-A124-3888-4F25C19CFDB7")
        btLight.name = "Hue Bloom"
        let lightController = HueBTLightController(light: btLight)
        weak var bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager.sharedInstance
        bluetoothManager?.selectLight(lightController.light!)
        bluetoothManager?.delegate += lightController
        return lightController
    }
```

In my test methods, I am getting the object of this class and unit testing the respective functions of that class.

```
    func testSetColorModel()
    {
       let lightController = setupLightController()
    }
```

Basically, the problem is that the object is returned before the delegate methods of HueBTLightController are executed. How can I wait for the delegate calls to be finished and then return the object in the test method? Please help me solve this.

Comment: You should look at using Expectations: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/testing/how-to-test-asynchronous-functions-using-expectation. These allow your code to wait for an async task to complete, you can specify how long it should wait and when it should complete

Comment: expectation mentioned above is definitely one way to handle this issue, but you didn't provide enough information. Are `bluetoothManager` calls synchronous or asynchronous? what "delegate calls to be finished" means for your test, i.e. do you have any indication that they completed? how do you know they finished?

Comment: bluetotthmanager calls are asynchronous... I do not have any indication of when the delegate calls are completed. Can you please tell me how to achieve that?